# ASP.NET GridView bind two field into one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have ASP.NET GridView in my web app and would like to bind two fields into one column and use string formatting. I am providing example below, is it possible to implement into GridView?

I have two data fields `Name` and `DefaultParam` and would like to display these fields into one GridView column.

Like this

```
Name=DefaultParam
```

If DefaultParam value is empty I would like to show only `Name` value and do not include `=`

I was using Repeater and code below to achieve this but now decided to move data display to GridView

```
<%#Eval("Name")%>
<%# (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DefaultParam").ToString())) ? "= " + Eval("DefaultParam"):"" %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a TemplateField and put your logic in there:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("Name") + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DefaultParam").ToString())) ? "= " + Eval("DefaultParam"):""%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Another option would be to use a Property on your object to do that logic for you behind the scenes and just use that as a BoundField, but you didn't mention what the object is your binding is.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple write server-side code between `<%# ...  %>` as you write in code behind. just put it in '' (between single quotes) .

```
<asp:Lable id="lblxx" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("Name") + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Eval("DefaultParam")))) ? "= " + Eval("DefaultParam"):"" %>' />
```

Follow this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288031.aspx) link  to know that how to Custom Formatting Based Upon Data using Template Fields.